# JDK 8+ is required while the path is pointing to version 0

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open VSCode a tab shows the following:

```
#   Path
1   ~/programs/jdk-12.0.1 CurrentInvalid
JDK 8+ is required while the path is pointing to version 0
```

The terminal shows the version:

```
$ javac -version 
javac 12.0.1
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/stephane/programs/jdk-12.0.1
$ whereis javac
javac: /home/stephane/programs/jdk1.12.0.1/bin/javac
```

The .profile file contains:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/programs/jdk-12.0.1
export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_OPTS=""
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I tried renaming the directory to `jdk1.12.0.1` but it changed nothing to the error:

```
1   ~/programs/jdk1.12.0.1 CurrentInvalid
JDK 8+ is required while the path is pointing to version 0
```

Why is `VSCode 1.38.1` on `Ubuntu 16.04` not accepting my Java version ?

Comment: What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` show you?

Comment: It shows `/home/stephane/programs/jdk-12.0.1`

Comment: It sounds like VSCode is taking the second part of the version number: it wants JDK 1.**8** or higher, and it thinks JDK 12.**0**.1 is lower, because 0 < 8. Rather foolish, if so; it shouldn't hardcode the assumption that JDKs are always 1.x.

Comment: I tried renaming the directory, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Where is `javac` in your system? Show output of `whereis javac`, please

Comment: I updated the question to show it is in `/home/stephane/programs/jdk1.12.0.1/bin/javac`

Comment: You has wrong JAVA_HOME environment. It should be `/home/stephane/programs/jdk1.12.0.1` according to location of `javac`. Don’t forget to restart your shell session to make environment changes take place.

Comment: The JAVA_HOME changed too when renaming the JDK directory. It is now `/home/stephane/programs/jdk1.12.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

I changed the SDK to `jdk-11.0.5` and still had the exact same issue.

The settings could not find it in `~/programs/jdk-11.0.5` too.

Only when I replaced the `~` with the absolute path as in `/home/stephane/programs/jdk-11.0.5` and closed and restarted the editor, did it work.

Note too that the suggested restart with the editor notification seemed not to update the settings change. I had to close the editor and open it again for the settings change to be seen by the editor.